# Unexpected status line while getting response from server on android app

Tags: java, android, http, client-server, esp8266

I am establishing server-client communication between Android app and ESP8266 NodeMCU-1.0. The ESP is creating server on specified network and the mobile is connecting to same network.

For testing purpose I am sending "try123" string when the send button is pressed. And receiving appropriate response on the serial monitor of IDE (i.e. data is received on server). But the server response which is "Test_successful" string. I am sending this string to client using `client.print`. In app I am toasting the server response.

The problem is that if I am making the HTTP request using browser using the locally generated URL, then the response "Test_successful" is visible. But In app toast it's showing empty and while debugging it's showing error Unexpected line status.

ESP code (server side):

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>    
const char* ssid = "DARSHAN95";
const char* password = "12345678";
//const char* ssid = "TP-LINK_42C148";
//const char* password = "";
// Create an instance of the server
// specify the port to listen on as an argument
WiFiServer server(80);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);  
  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void loop() {
  // Check if a client has connected
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  // Wait until the client sends some data
  Serial.println("new client");
  while(!client.available()){
    delay(1);
  }
  // Read the first line of the request
  String req = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  Serial.println(req);
  client.flush();
  // Match the request
  //client.flush();

  delay(100);
   // Send the response to the client
client.print("Test_Sucessfull");
  delay(200);
  Serial.println("Client disonnected");
}
```

Android App code:
Please ignore the text input block on the and its code.

```java
package com.example.access.test123;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText Message;
    Button Send;
    String data;
    HttpURLConnection http;
    String sendingMessage;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Message = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
        Send.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HttpAsync task = new HttpAsync();
                task.execute();
            }
        });
    }


    public void sendDataMethod() throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        sendingMessage = Message.getText().toString();
        String data = "Error";
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        //Sending Data
        try{

            String ip = "http://192.168.43.76/?try123";
            //String address = ip + sendingMessage;
            //URL url = new URL(address);
            URL url = new URL(ip);
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            http = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
            http.setRequestMethod("POST"); // PUT is another valid option
            http.setDoOutput(true);
            http.setDoInput(true);

            //Server Response
            int i =  http.getResponseCode();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            data = sb.toString();
        }

            catch(IOException e){;
            Log.d("Error2", e.toString());

        }
        finally {
            try{
                if(reader != null) {
                    reader.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException ex){
                Log.d("Error3", ex.toString());

            }
        }
    }
    private class HttpAsync extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            try {
                sendDataMethod();
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                Log.d("Error", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
            super.onPostExecute(o);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging results:

```
02/07 22:40:23: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk A:\New folder\Test123\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.access.test123/com.example.access.test123.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.access.test123.test | com.example.access.test123
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.access.test123.test | com.example.access.test123
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.access.test123.test | com.example.access.test123
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.access.test123.test | com.example.access.test123
Waiting for application to come online: com.example.access.test123.test | com.example.access.test123
Connecting to com.example.access.test123
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/art: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8601', transport: 'socket'
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1436)
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.access.test123-2/lib/arm64
I/art: Starting a blocking GC HeapTrim
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/art: Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4, Parent = null, this = DecorView@3280086[]
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: DecorView@3280086[MainActivity], this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@d5cc9ee
D/OpenGLRenderer: Dumper init 4 threads <0x7c6a19ee40>
D/OpenGLRenderer: <com.example.access.test123> is running.
D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7c6773f880
D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{500151c com.example.access.test123/com.example.access.test123.MainActivity,ident = 0}
V/PhoneWindow: DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0, Parent = ViewRoot{500151c com.example.access.test123/com.example.access.test123.MainActivity,ident = 0}, this = DecorView@3280086[MainActivity]
D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7c6773f880 initialize window=0x7c73e55e00, title=com.example.access.test123/com.example.access.test123.MainActivity
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7c73e55e00)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
D/OpenGLRenderer: Created EGL context (0x7c6a19f600)
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.init: enable enhancement 1
I/OpenGLRenderer: Get disable program binary service property (0)
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program atlas...
I/ProgramBinary/Service: ProgramBinaryService client side disable debugging.
I/ProgramBinary/Service: ProgramBinaryService client side disable binary content debugging.
D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getReady
D/ProgramBinary/Service: BpProgramBinaryService.getProgramBinaryData
I/OpenGLRenderer: Program binary detail: Binary length is 249276, program map length is 124.
I/OpenGLRenderer: Succeeded to mmap program binaries. File descriptor is 74, and path is /dev/ashmem.
I/OpenGLRenderer: No need to use file discriptor anymore, close fd(74).
D/OpenGLRenderer: Initializing program cache from 0x0, size = -1
D/MALI: eglCreateImageKHR:513: [Crop] 0 0 896 1344  img[896 1344] 
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7c73e55e00,api=1)
W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
D/OpenGLRenderer: CacheTexture 3 upload: x, y, width height = 0, 0, 189, 441
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 0
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 34359738371
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 5242945
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 5242944
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 240518168576
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 68724719680
V/InputMethodManager: onWindowFocus: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{8687c92 VFED..CL. .F....ID 228,66-851,212 #7f070042 app:id/message} softInputMode=288 first=true flags=#81810100
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 103084458052
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
I/System.out: [socket][0] connection /192.168.43.76:80;LocalPort=-1(0)

              [ 02-07 22:40:39.251 29396:29665 D/         ]
              [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.access.test123 :80 
I/System.out: [socket][/192.168.43.1:49348] connected
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest>>
I/System.out: [OkHttp] sendRequest<<
D/Error2: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: Test_Sucessfull
D/WindowClient: Add to mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{3957537 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@d5cc9ee
D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7c56092d40
D/ViewRootImpl[Toast]: hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{f7a400d Toast,ident = 1}
D/Surface: Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7c58339e00)
D/OpenGLRenderer: CanvasContext() 0x7c56092d40 initialize window=0x7c58339e00, title=Toast
D/Surface: Surface::connect(this=0x7c58339e00,api=1)
W/libEGL: [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display*, void*, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface**, egl_color_buffer_format*, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
D/OpenGLRenderer: ProgramCache.generateProgram: 1
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7c58339e00,api=1)
D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x7c58339e00,api=1)
D/WindowClient: Remove from mViews: android.widget.LinearLayout{3957537 V.E...... ......ID 0,0-156,140}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@d5cc9ee
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=28KB, data=28KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=28KB
I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
```

**Note: At D/Error2: java.net.ProtocolException: Unexpected status line: Test_Sucessfull**

The string is received but with above error.

Results:
IDE monitor displaying data sent from client i.e. app
[image: IDE monitor displaying data sent from client i.e app]

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found the solution, the error was with the syntax of the response packet sent from ESP side

so just replaced

```
client.print("Test_Successfull");
```

with

```
client.print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nConnection: Closed\r\n\r\nTest_Successful");
```